# int.TryParse doesn't work with values posted by IE or Edge

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, internet-explorer

I feel completely stupid facing this issue.
I have simple C# code in MVC application where I need to evaluate string as valid int and another string as valid DateTime. Everything works fine when calling application from Chrome, Opera, Firefox. But when calling applicatin from IE or Edge (on multiple PCs) the evaluation fails.

My code:

```
if(!int.TryParse(s, out i))
   {
        // something
   }
```

I've tried using CultureInfo and NumberFormatInfo with no efect.
The string value is **niether null nor empty** and contains int value in text format.
The same behavior is with evaluating string as DateTime.
Really don't know where is the problem...
Thanks for help.

Whole code:
1.Controller

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("RatingDetail/{ratingID:int}/{time}/{value:int}")]
    public JsonResult RatingDetail(int ratingID, string time, int value)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var context = new SenzorikaEntities())
            {
                var rd = new RatingDB();
                //  URL must not contain ':', so we are sending time 
                //  in format 0_00_00 instead of 0:00:00.
                //  So we have to replace back...
                time = time.Replace('_', ':');

                //  This line fails when browsing in IE
                //  and yes sould by .TryParse, I know
                var timeDB = DateTime.Parse(System.DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + " " + time);

                var detialID = rd.InsertRatingDetail(context, ratingID, timeDB, value);
                return Json(detialID, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorLog.LogError(ex, "Error when saving values.");
            throw;
        }
    }
```

2. Javascript

   ```
   function saveRating(percent, time) {
           // model ID
           var rid = $("#RatingID").val();
           var timeConvert = time.replace(':', '_').replace(':', '_');
   } 




   $.ajax(
       {
           statusCode: {
               500: showError('some error text'),
               200: showError('')
           },
           url: '/RatingDetail/' + rid + '/' + timeConvert + '/' + percent,
           async: true,
           type: 'GET',
           dataType: 'json',
           success:
           function (response) {
               if (response == undefined || response == "0")
                   showError('some error text');
           },
           error: 
               function (response) {
                   showError(");

               }
       });
   ```

One more interesting point. I tracked the page by Fiddler. The GET request (called by AJAX) in Google appears normal:/RatingDetail/69/0_00_01/4
But in Edge: /RatingDetail/70/%E2%80%8E0%E2%80%8E_%E2%80%8E00%E2%80%8E_%E2%80%8E05/9
The URL is decoded back in controller automaticaly, but may be somehow numbers are no longer numbers...

Comment: Why are you doing this instead of binding to a model?

Comment: What's the contents of `s`

Comment: Well, one value is binded to model but filled by JavaScript so I rather made model property string and then evaluate at C#. The second value is passed in URL by Ajax call and ist's time, but you cant pass time in time format to URL, so I use JavaScript to reformat the value from 0:00:00 to 0_00_00 and then in c# evaluating that the parametr contains numbers...

Comment: the content of `s` is "0"

Comment: Of course you can bind a time to a model (to a property which is typeof `TimeSpan`)

Comment: So.. the problem is probably **not** the `int.TryParse`, **but** getting the value from javascript/ajax into `s`.

Comment: May be this is the problem. The value `0` of `s`param when passed by IE **is not** evalueted as integer, opposite passed  by Chrome **is** evalueted as integer.

Comment: @Stephen I also need pass time value (eg. 0:00:05) through param in calling GET method. Can't use timespan there, or I'm wrong?

Comment: Of course you can.- `../yourController/Edit?time=0:00:05` will bind correctly to `public ActionResult Edit(TimeSpan time)` (and there is no such thing as an integer in your browser). And is `s="0"` and `i` is typeof `int`, then it works perfectly so you have not shown the correct code

Comment: You can't pass letter colon in url. EG `../edit/61/0:00:00/0` Server responds with potentionaly dangerours request error...

Comment: @Stephen I made interesting test. I added property of TimeSpan to my model and displayed in view in textbox. I'm filling the value by timer in Javascript. Code looks: Model:`public class MyViewModel {  public TimeSpan MyTimeSpan { get; set; }// other properties}`View: `@using (Html.BeginForm()){ <input type="submit" id="btStop" value="Stop" onclick = "return StopWatch();" /> @Html.EditorFor(x => x.MyTimeSpan, new { @id = "MyTimeSpan" })}` JavaScript: `function myTimer() {
        
        $('#MyTimeSpan').val(date.toLocaleTimeString());
    } `

Comment: @Stephen To that point is everything OK. When I made PostBack in Chrome the value in MyViewModel of MyTimeSpan is correct, e.g 0:00:18. When I made PostBack in Edge the value of MyTimeSpan is always defalut value: 0:00:00.

Comment: You have not included any of that info in your question. No one can possible give you an answer until you show ALL the relevant code

Comment: I've added code ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the culprite...
I made an array form the string I needed to evaluate as int and I saw that response from IE or Edge **had more chars** then response from Chrome/Opera/Firefox.
Response from **IE had added quotation marks** chars.
You can see at pictures.
The input string was 0:00:10 for IE and 0:00:12 for Chrome.

[Response from Chrome - everything OK:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnMXR.png)

[Response from IE/Edge - added quotation marks chars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpqdM.png)

As you see, I can't make timespan (or datetime) format from string that contains extra quotation marks. But this was not visible when debugging until I made a char array...

So I had to make workaround and clear the extra quotation mark chars.

```
public static string IEHackforTime(string time)
    {
        string newTime = "";
        var arr = time.ToCharArray();
        foreach( var c in arr)
        {
            if (Char.IsNumber(c) || c==':' )
            {
                newTime += c.ToString(); // No need of StringBuilder, array is small enough
            }
        }
        return newTime;
    }
```